# Cannot debug with Comma IDE

Tags: debugging, raku, commaide

I'm not able to debug any raku script/module with Comma IDE.

I created a new 'hello world'-like project and set up according the [this manual](https://commaide.com/docs/running).

But the debugger does not stop on breakpoints.

If the "Start Suspended" property is unchecked, then the script runs until the end.

If the property is checked, then it starts suspended, but when I step over, the script runs until the end.

Probably I'm missing something obvious, but cannot see it... Perhaps I need to install some raku module?

I'm using Comma 2020.07 Community and Rakudo Star v2020.05.1

When trying to debug, I get this error con the console log:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: specified network name is no longer available.

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.PendingFuture.get(PendingFuture.java:183)
    at org.edument.moarvm.RemoteInstance.lambda$connect$0(RemoteInstance.java:76)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn.subscribeActual(ObservableObserveOn.java:44)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:10514)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$1.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:39)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$1.run(Scheduler.java:134)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:59)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:51)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: specified network name is no longer available.

    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Iocp.java:299)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:389)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: My experience is that this is going to depened heavily on the JVM that's installed. There might also be some errors in the console. Did you check that?

Comment: Sadly, this is a long standing bug in MoarVM implementation which cannot be fixed from Comma side. The common workaround is to add more code lines, say `say 42`, around the statement you want to stop at and mark them as breakpoints. This increases chances of stopping at some of them and then you can step over to the needed one. Usually around 8-10 such statements is more than enough, but it depends and for some code it does not help at all.

Comment: @Takao. That didn't seem to work for me. I created a simple hello world script and repeated the `say` statement more than 40 times and marked checkpoints for every statement. I still had the same problem :<

Comment: @jjmerelo Yes, it seems that some java error is recorded once I try to debug. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @Takao, yes, I'm using windows

Comment: @Julio there are not lots of things we can do, other than suggest to change the JVM version; you'll need to cut and paste those errors and submit a report to the Comma creators.

Comment: @Julio the connection issue you provided is a known Windows-only Comma bug. Given number of Windows users is increasing, we will spend more time attempting to fix those for next releases.

Comment: @Julio I'm curious if this now seems fixed?